# Django signal get request full path

Tags: django, path, request, signals

I wrote a signal in my django project, inside I want to send an email with the full path of my website. But to do so, I need to get the request object inside the signal, how could I do that? Thanks.

```
    @receiver(pre_save, sender=AccessRequest)
    def email_if_access_true(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        #How can I get the full path of my website here?
        pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put following code in your `pre_save` signal receiver:

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import get_current_site
current_site = get_current_site(request=None)
domain = current_site.domain
protocol = "http"
```

You can generate absolute url to your website in email by passing required context variables to template. If `access_request` is instance in your case and there is one [get_abosulte_url()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) method in your `AccessRequest` model, then following line in email template will give you absolute url.

```
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% access_request.get_absolute_url %}
```

Reference - [PasswordResetForm](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4.5/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L189-L242) in `django.contrib.auth.form`.

Answer (score 4):

If you don’t have access to the request object, you can use the get_current() method of the Site model’s manager.

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

@receiver(pre_save, sender=AccessRequest)
def email_if_access_true(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    current_site = Site.objects.get_current()
    if current_site.domain == 'foo.com':
        #do other stuff here
    else:
        pass
```

you need to ensure that you defined `SITE_ID=1` in your settings

Comment: wrt/ SITE_ID=1 : that is, unless you're really using the site framework to serve more than one site from the same project ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you don’t have access to the request object, you can use the get_current() method of the Site model’s manager.

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

@receiver(pre_save, sender=MyModel)
def my_function_without_request(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    current_site = Site.objects.get_current()
    domain = current_site.domain
    # Do something
```

To enable the sites framework, follow these steps:

1. Add 'django.contrib.sites' to your INSTALLED_APPS setting.
2. Define a SITE_ID setting: SITE_ID = 1
3. Run migrate.

[Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/sites/](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/sites/)

To set the correct name and domain for your project, you can use a data migration.

To start, make an empty migration file you can work from (Django will put the file in the right place, suggest a name, and add dependencies for you):

```
python manage.py makemigrations --empty yourappname
```

Then, open up the file and create a new function and have RunPython use it.

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from django.db import migrations

def set_name_and_domain():
    one = Site.objects.all()[0]
    one.domain = 'yourdomain.com'
    one.name = 'Your Name'
    one.save()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('yourappname', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(set_name_and_domain),
    ]
```

All of this will save your domain and site name in your database where you can access it without having the request object. So far I have not found a better way to do this.

[Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/#data-migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/#data-migrations)