# Django: How to get domain name inside a signal handler

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to send an email with my website address from django signal. I found this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15521046/2385132 and proceeded as was advised in the accepted answer, but when using that code, I'm getting this error:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_host'`

Which is coming from the `get_current_site` in my code:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel)
def post_obj_save(sender, instance: MyModel, **kwargs):
    def _get_html(obj: MyModel):
        return render_to_string('confirmation_email.html', _get_context(obj))

    def _get_context(obj: MyModel):
        current_site = get_current_site(request=None)
        domain = current_site.domain
        action = reverse('obj_activation', request=None, format=None, kwargs={})
        url = '{protocol}://{domain}/{action}'.format(protocol=PROTOCOL, domain=domain, action=action)        
        return {
            'header': _('Thank you for registering with ASDF.'),
            'prompt': _('In order to be able to log in into ASDF administrator panel, you have to activate your account using'),
            'link_name': _('this link'),
            'activation_url': url
        }

    send_mail(
        _('ASDF account activation'),
        _get_html(instance),
        EMAIL_FROM,
        [obj.owner.email],
        fail_silently=False,
    )
```

So the question is: how do I get full url of my view in a signal?

Btw. I'm using `django-rest-framework`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In recent Django versions (probably your case), the domain is *always* taken from the request *if `SITE_ID` is not defined in your settings*. See [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/sites/#django.contrib.sites.shortcuts.get_current_site) change introduced in 1.8 Django version:

> Changed in Django 1.8:
>
> This function will now lookup the current site based on
>   request.get_host() if the SITE_ID setting is not defined.

So, in your case `request=None` you must have the [`sites` framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/sites/) enabled, an entry for your current site/domain and `SITE_ID` setting pointing to the right instance in the `Site` table, try this and you will see :)

Comment: Actually I'm using django v1.9.7 :). I think I'll go with your answer, so thank you.